# Create or append to a list in a dictionary - can this be shortened?

Tags: python, dictionary

Can this Python code be shortened and still be readable using itertools and sets?

```
result = {}
for widget_type, app in widgets:
    if widget_type not in result:
        result[widget_type] = []
    result[widget_type].append(app)
```

I can think of this only:

```
widget_types = zip(*widgets)[0]
dict([k, [v for w, v in widgets if w == k]) for k in set(widget_types)])
```

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You can use a `defaultdict(list)`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
for widget_type, app in widgets:
    result[widget_type].append(app)
```

Comment: +1 As stated in https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects : *This technique is simpler and faster than an equivalent technique using `dict.setdefault()`*

Comment: Related: [How to convert a `default_dict` to `dict`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20428703/2436175).

Answer (score 133):

An alternative to `defaultdict` is to use the `setdefault` method of standard dictionaries:

```
 result = {}
 for widget_type, app in widgets:
     result.setdefault(widget_type, []).append(app)
```

This relies on the fact that lists are mutable, so what is returned from setdefault is the same list as the one in the dictionary, therefore you can append to it.

Comment: And that's my Python nugget to learn for the day. Thanks, Daniel. :)

Comment: My personal opinion: I am opting for `defaultdict` because `setdefault` is, at least in my experience, the method with the most unintelligible name I have ever seen across any language. Also [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) suggest to use `defaultdict` _This technique is simpler and faster than an equivalent technique using `dict.setdefault()`_

Answer (score 6):

may be a bit slow but works

```
result = {}
for widget_type, app in widgets:
    result[widget_type] = result.get(widget_type, []) + [app]
```

Comment: why would this be slower than the other solutions?

Comment: It would be slower because the concat operator (+) creates a new list every time, while append() adds the element to the existing list.